# Switch between .net web services dynamically

Tags: .net, web-services

I have a .net web service reference and I want to pass it to a function in a different library (ie, a lib without the service reference).  Unfortunately I want to pass two different kinds of services to this function.

I know all about interfaces and how this should be done, but I need to know how this is done within the microsoft service reference framework.  I like how you can right click and add a service, but now I need to pass the generated class into a function and I want to know how other people manage this.

Comment: What do you mean you want to pass a reference to a function? What will the function do with the reference? One doesn't normally pass a web service reference to a function.

Comment: I have a lib that contains all my logic, packaging up requests and dealing with the return values, etc.  But I want to pass in the service, ie the live one or a test one. I don't have access to the live one but I've generated a test service using the same interface so in theory I wanted to swap either in or out.

Comment: Again, this isn't clear: what do you mean "pass in the service"? Do you mean you want to pass in an instance of the proxy class?

Comment: Yes, the problem is, although they have the same interface they do not share a common interface in code.  Does this make sense?

Comment: No, it makes no sense. Show us how you would use it if it were only one service.

Comment: It might help if you told us what you're trying to accomplish. I think you're making assumptions about _how_ to accomplish it, and you're asking about the _how_. But your assumptions are false, so your "how" makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear. It almost sounds like you don't understand how computer programs work.

I'm going to assume that you actually do, but simply haven't expressed your question well. I will make a guess that your issue is that you don't know how to use two different implementations of the same service and switch between them.

There are several overloads of the constructor for a service reference proxy class. One of these accepts an endpoint. Simply pass the URL of the service you want to that constructor, and you're all set. At worse, this means that you need to pass the URL to your library so that your library can create the correct instance.

Comment: Well, I do not understand how this particular aspect of the framework works, so bear with me.

Comment: I think I see now, I don't need to create a service reference for each one, is that it?

Comment: Okay, well I did not know about the constructors and endpoints.  I'll let you have your point because it helped, despite your trolling.

Comment: What do you mean "trolling"? I wasn't sure what you meant. I made a guess and it turned out to be correct. Why be insulting?